# Flash CS5 and custom button making

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5

Just learning Flash (using version CS5) as part of a course and making my own buttons which is going ok. Problem is, I can make buttons with behaviours using the default custom libraries option using their buttons, yet when I try to make my own I just get the frames timeline (after I make the button a symbol and try to edit it in edit mode) Frames timeline shows, instead of up, over, down and hit - which does show with the default library button. I have also tried to reset my workstation to 'developer' in case I have somehow hidden the option which works to an extent but I can't get it fully back to the default view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "convert to Symbol" (or hit F8), you'll get a pop up screen, the first field is labelled 'Name', just below you will see a dropdown labelled 'Type' that is by default set to **MovieClip**, change that to **Button** and there you go!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! The Flash Program interface can be sometimes difficult to work with, patience and don't despair!

Comment: Yes, it's very fiddly and lots of people have openly disliked Flash but like you say, perseverance is key. Thanks again Danii!.